# What happened in the Forgotten Realms between 3.5 and 4e?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, campaign-settings, forgotten-realms

I don't remember where I heard or read this, but I seem to recall there being some sort of cataclysmic event between 3.5 and 4e.

A few (related) questions -

1. What exactly happened between 3.5 and 4e?
2. How much do the current inhabitants of the Forgotten Realms know about what happened?
3. How much game-world time has passed between editions?
4. What geographic locations were affected by the events between editions, and how do they affect 4e play?

Comment: There is a summary of this in the beginning of the 4e Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes there was, the cataclysmic event is called the [Spellplague](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Spellplague).  Mystra dies, huge upheavals happen for a decade including natural disasters, arcane magic goes away for a time, etc.  I don't think it escaped any Realmsian's notice, that's for sure; the effects were blatant and profound.  The [4e guide](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Forgotten_Realms_Campaign_Guide) is set in 1479 DR while [the 3e one](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Forgotten_Realms_Campaign_Setting_3rd_edition) was in 1372 DR, so nearly a hundred years passed in world before the coming of 4e.

Comment: Also Abeir and Toril got together again and swapped some lands if I recall correctly.  Elminster's still alive too but not quite as powerful anymore.

Comment: Drizzt's wife dies, Neverwinter gets worse (a whole campaign setting was made for that), and the Abolethic Sovereignty harnesses the power of the spellplague.

Comment: @mirv120 note that, before the 4e books, there was no sign of a different, parallel planet called Abeir and Abeir-toril was the full name of Toril

Answer (score 4):

Specifically to the Geographic locations bit, the whole map was rescaled. Several countries/nations were removed/condensed/destroyed. Anauroch was removed, and replaced by the nation of Netheril.The level of the Sea of Fallen Stars fell, changing a number of port cities to land-locked. An entire new continent was inherted from Abeir.

Comment: "Rescaled"? It changed size?

Comment: Well, enough areas on the map were resized to be considered the whole map by me :)

Comment: Rescaled isn't the right word to me.  Remade would be better.  Rescaled would indicate that the dimensions of the planet changed.  The geography changed.  I have the the map from 3E and 4E right next to each other, the scale is identical IIRC.

Comment: What parts of the geographic change are "in world changes" vs "out world changes"? I recall WOTC saying that the map was condensed to have more land and less sea, but that this was not a physical change -- the world has retroactively always had the new shape.

Comment: @Sean I don't know, but there were a lot of out-of-world changes, including the whole thing with "Abeir" and "Toril" meaning entirely different places than before. If the water-to-land ratio changed, I'd expect that to be an out-of-world change. A new question asking which of the changes were out-of-world changes might be good.